# undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.state.events[i].summary')

Tags: react-native, google-calendar-api, fetch-api

I am newbie to react native and trying to figure out what is wrong here but I could not find any solution. I am using Google Calendar API to get data from a calendar and I am able to get the data but when I try to parse it and render it, I face with this error.

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, Text, StatusBar, Image, AppRegistry, ScrollView, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import glamorous from "glamorous-native";
import { Calendar, Agenda } from 'react-native-calendars';
import { bColor, pColor } from "../style/colors"
import request from 'superagent'

import PostItem from "../elements/PostItem"

export default class AppCalendar extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: "Calendar",
    });

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            events:[]
        })
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        let postsUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/apiKey
        fetch(postsUrl)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({
                    events: response
                })
            })
    }


    fetchData(){
            let e = []
            if (this.state.events != null) {
                for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
                    let newEvent = {}
                    newEvent.title = this.state.events[i].summary
                    newEvent.location = this.state.events[i].location
                    newEvent.startDate = this.state.events[i].start.date || this.state.events[i].start.dateTime
                    newEvent.endDate = this.state.events[i].end.date || this.state.events[i].end.dateTime
                    if(newEvent.startDate)
                    e.push(newEvent)
                }
                    return e
                
            }
            else {
                return 'yanlis'
            } 
    }


    render() {
        console.log('length is', this.state.events.length)
        return (
            <View>
                   <Text>{this.fetchData()}</Text>
            </View>    
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` and `setState` are asynchronous. When you're rendering, `this.state.events` is going to just be an empty array as the data will not be set updated yet. So when you use access it in your for loop in `fetchData()`, you will get `undefined` as `this.state.events` is just going to be your initial value of `[]`.

Also, your if statement:

```
if (this.state.events != null)
```

does nothing since `this.state.events` is initialized to `[]`. It will always execute and never do what's in your `else` statement.

I suggest going over how async code works in JavaScript since it's heavily used in React / React Native (`fetch`, `setState`, etc.).

Comment: I looked at it and i am a little confused. When the code is started, the componentDidmount will work and the events will be filled from the api but this is going to be happen after fetchData i guess. So, the event will be empty. How could i make it work like fetchData works after componentDidMount? Am i doing it wrong by putting fetch in the component did mount since it will be activated with the render. @Michael Cheng

Comment: @uguryiilmz if you check length of the array and not if its null and  if you move your `this.state.events` control to render from `fetchData()` it will fix your problem. `{ this.state.events.length > 0 && <Text>{this.fetchData()}</Text> }`

Comment: I have done it and now I am getting a blank page which I don't know why. I am trying to show the all json data in the interface but it is just blank page even though array is filled with data @bennygenel